# Should I use past simple or present perfect for something that happened a second ago?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

I'm stepping out onto the balcony and want to say about it after I've done it. Should I say: "I've stepped out onto the balcony" or "I stepped out onto the balcony"?

If a person says something to me and I realize that I don't understand them, should I reply: "I haven't understood what you've just said" or "I didn't understand what you've just said"?

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, the present perfect is more precise.  The simple past is completely fine too though, and you can still qualify the simple past to get that "present perfect" meaning, with an adverbial phrase like "just now."

For instance, "I just now stepped out onto the balcony" and "I didn't understand what you said just now."

Comment: Thanks. It seems that when I use past simple (didn't) in that case it means that I now understand what they've just said, but in reality I still don't understand when they have just said.

Comment: The past simple is used with the sense that, at the time the words were said, they conveyed nothing to you. If you now understood you would say "I didn't understand at first".